# Is there a way to read query string param inside app_init of Angular 6 spa?

Tags: angular6

We have a need to pass a parameter to angular SPA during the initialization part. We load some data in app module during `init_app()` method.

### app.module.ts

```
export function init_app(dataService: DataService) {
  return () => dataService.initializeMyApp();
}
```

When I go inside `initializeMyApp()` method, I cant access route or activatedroute classes because the route is not loaded yet. How do I access query string in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

answer to this post works perfectly for me. Just a a function and perform this task in java script. During App Init the angular has is not loaded yet so we dont have access to query string parameters inside.